# Python - Define printer tray for different pages of a PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, printing

Is there any way to define the trays of a PDF file and send it to printer in Python?

The problem is: The client receives a PCL file from other partner to print, but he can't change the configurations of this PCL and transform it to PDF file, because when try print the PCL the printer use only one tray among its four trays.

My requirement is: Open PDF file and show the pages to the user and he will select the tray for each page (because in trays have papers with different colors).

The printer is Kyocera Ecosys P3260DN.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The PDF language does not support this as it is device specific and PDF is by design device agnostic. You would have to look at another language (such as PCL) to select the tray and any other options, and then send the correct pages afterwards. So more than likely you'll be looking at a hybrid approach.

Comment: Thanks David! We have the PCL file, but we don't know how to change the trays of this file? Could you please advice what are the best options to edit the PCL file (not only in Python)?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I know PDF, but not PCL I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry! Is it possible for PDF (define tray for each page)? I think that I could develop a function that show pages of a PDF and the user could select a tray for each page... Let me know if I got well your answer and thanks again =)